# How to print a random string with non-repetitive letters?

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a c++ program to print a random 10 letter string from a-z (ascii code 97 to 122) with non-repetitive letters. I have written this code which sometimes runs perfectly but most of the times the while loop runs infinitely.
Where's the problem?

(EDIT: setting flag=0 at the beginning of while fixes the problem)

```
void randomstring()
{int i,j,flag=1;
 char x, s[20]=" ";
 srand(time(0));
 for(i=0;i<10;i++)
 {flag=1; //ensure entry into while
  while(flag)
  {x=rand()%26+97; //get random letter from a-z
   for(j=0;j<10;j++)
   {if(x==s[j]) //match with existing letters
     flag=2; //if matched, try again
   }
   if(flag!=2)
   {s[i]=x; //if doesn't match, add to string
    flag=0; //exit while
   }
  }
 }
 cout<<s;
}
```

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41015311/picking-about-random-character-without-repetition-c)

Comment: use step-by-step debug

Answer (score 3):

(Currently the loop will not terminate if a duplicate character is spotted.) But aside from this, the code is nasty for a couple of other reasons:

1. You're assuming ASCII *encoding* which is not guaranteed by the standard.
2. Sampling with replacement can cause problems with looping, and also can create statistical anomalies (although with a crude generator like `rand()` these will be no worse than the generator itself).

One solution is to write

`char s[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', .../*ToDo - type out all the other letters*/, 'z'}`

and *shuffle* this using

```
std::random_shuffle(std::begin(s), std::end(s));
```

and read out the first 10 elements of `s`.

Comment: Can you please explain why loop doesn't terminate when duplicate is found?

Answer (score 1):

Once the flag is set to 2, it is stuck. You should reset the flag to 1 inside the while loop.